# Jersey - The @Context annotation for injection. How does it work?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I was looking at a good [REST tutorial using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#crud_class).
Down the page, there is a web resource that is built which is entitled `TodoResource` which itself contains two instance variables

```java
public class TodoResource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    Request request;

    String id;

    public TodoResource(UriInfo uriInfo, Request request, String id) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        this.request = request;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I was wondering exactly how the `UriInfo` and `Request` instance variables are initialized? I know that using the `@Context` annotation allows for information to be injected, but at what point does this happen? Will this be handled automatically by Jersey?

Comment: I don't know the details, but yes, Jersey will automagically initialize those variables for you behind the scenes. If you need to know the details of how it works, in Eclipse, you could put a "watchpoint" on one of those variables, which tells the debugger to break whenever that variable is modified. Then you can look at the stack trace and see what Jersey class is modifying it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Jersey **doesn't modify** the class, but it **creates** it on every request from the client.

**After** the class constructor was invoked, the context fields are injected.
(Should you try to access those fields inside the constructor, they will be `null`)

In your case, the class wouldn't need a specific constructor, so just:

```
public TodoResource () {
    // in most cases the ctor stays empty.
    // don't do much work here, remember: the ctor is invoked at every client request
}
```

But inside methods (which represent web-resources) annotated with `@POST, @GET, ...` you would have access to context fields.

Answer (score 27):

I've run into some interesting results with the [Rules of Injection](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2759), here's what I've found:

```
public class TodoResource{
  @Context
  UriInfo uriInfo; // Set second
  public TodoResource(@Context UriInfo value){
    uriInfo = value; // Set first (makes sense)
  }
  @Context
  public void setUriInfo(UriInfo value){
    uriInfo = value; // Set third
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

Use *@PostConstruct* method annotation:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

@Path("foo")
public class AuthResource {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public AuthResource() {
        //request is null
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        //request is NOT null
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
       //after rest method executing
    }
}
```