# Extract path params from container request

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to implement `ContainerRequestFilter` and the method `filter`.

How can I extract he path params from `ContainerRequest request`?

I can only see a direct method to extract the query and form parameters.

Comment: did you got  solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContainerRequest` doesn't seem to contain that information, but you can [inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140697/jersey-the-context-annotation-for-injection-how-does-it-work) a `UriInfo` into the filter and use that. See [`UriInfo.getPathParameters()`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathParameters%28%29).

Reference: [How to get the value of a PathParam outside a Resource class](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-value-of-a-PathParam-outside-a-Resource-class-td3849795.html)

Comment: Regarding the link to an answer from the forums - the links do not work.

Comment: Is it ok to inject it like an autowired parameter in the Filter class?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to use field injection. This won't look like it makes sense, since the filter is instantiated once, but Jersey will use a thread-local proxy to make the injection happen per-request behind the scenes.

Comment: The links works, but not what is written inside. for instance https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.2-ea/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequest.html

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yeah, the Jersey documentation is often down and it's very annoying. I usually google the class name and then use a cached page.

Comment: I used to have my ResourceFilterFactory and inside it the ContainerRequestFilter. When I put @Context
 HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest; inside the ResourceFilterFactory it worked fine, but when I put it inside the ContainerRequestFilter it was null. Any reasons for why it would happen?

Comment: @Odelya Are you using `new` to instantiate it yourself? Injection only works when Jersey does the instantiation. Otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: @PaulBellora  I'm using 
`@Provider
public class ReqFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo ...`
to inject UriInfo..
I'm getting uriInfo.getPath but uriInfo.getPathParameters() is throwing null pointer..
the resource has PathParam..

Any idea, what can go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

2018 answer:

```
containerRequest.getUriInfo().getPathParameters()
```

- http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/apidocs/2.11/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.html#getUriInfo()

Answer (score 0):

For Jersey you can get path params like this:

```
containerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters()
```

snippet for filter:

```
public class JerseyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext {
        containerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
      }
```